# change text color with angularjs

Tags: javascript, java, html, css, angularjs

I have this partial code:

```
<div style="margin-top:25px;"
     ng-class="{'color-red': $ctrl.clientStatus === 'Error', 'color-blue': $ctrl.clientStatus === 'Warning', 'color-green': $ctrl.clientStatus === 'OK'}">
    Status: {{$ctrl.filesToUploadClientStatus}}</div>
```

and this component code:

```
(function (app) {
    app.component('uploadFilesComponent', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/upload-files-partial.html',

        // bindings: {filesToUpload: '=', hasFilesOnServer : '='},
        controller: ['$scope', '$state','uploadService', function ($scope, $state, uploadService) {

...

            var self = this;

            var NO_FILES_TO_UPLOAD = "No files to upload";
            var WAITING_FOR_UPLOAD = "Waiting for upload";

            self.clientStatus = self.filesToUploadClientStatus.contains(WAITING_FOR_UPLOAD) ? 'OK' : 'Error';
...
}
```

why am i getting a broken html when adding this?

```
ng-class="{'color-red': $ctrl.clientStatus === 'Error', 'color-blue': $ctrl.clientStatus === 'Warning', 'color-green': $ctrl.clientStatus === 'OK'}">
        Status: {{$ctrl.filesToUploadClientStatus}}
```

Comment: Do you need the the `'` in your ng-class? Looking at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass, it doesn't look like the `'` is required

Comment: what do you mean with broken HTML? and what type is  `filesToUploadClientStatus`? The only use I know of contains in JavaScript is for HTML elements in order to see if they contain another element. Maybe is just my lack, but did you try to use indexOf or includes?